# Can ncompress compress a file to 99.99% rate?

Tags: linux, tar, compression

I'm using the old `ncompress` to create a backup file. And what I see is amazing:

```
[root@centos6 home]# ll -l -b mytest*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1073741824 Mar  8 13:41 mytest.iso
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      88099 Mar  9 10:26 mytest.iso.bak.Z
```

Here is the command I used:

```
compress -c mytest.iso>mytest.iso.bak.Z
```

The size of `mytest.iso` (which actually is centos6.8-livecd.iso) changed from 1073741824 (1.0G) to 88099 (87K).

But when I use:

```
tar -cvf mytest.iso.tar.gz mytest.iso
```

the tar.gz file doesn't change a lot in size:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1073745920 Mar  9 10:43 mytest.tar.gz
```

Is this normal? The iso file works just fine if I uncompress it.

Comment: It's not surprising that your `tar` example doesn't make the file much smaller (in fact it makes it larger), because `tar -cvf` won't do any compression. (The `tar` utility is not a compression program, though some versions - eg GNU tar - support compression with options such as `-z` or -`j`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compression algorithms have varying compression ratios depending on the properties of the data they are compressing.  For instance:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1m count=1024
$ compress -c test.img > test.img.Z
$ gzip -c test.img > test.img.gz
$ wc -c test.img test.img.gz test.img.Z
 1073741824 test.img
    4685486 test.img.gz
      84781 test.img.Z
 1078512091 total
```

Having a file made up of mostly repeated zeroes is probably a best-case situation for this algorithm.  Since you are getting similar compression ratios, and since your file is of such a round size (1GB), it is likely that the image is much larger than necessary and merely filled with repeated data.

---

Of course, `gzip`, `compress`, `bzip2`, and others will all have differing compression ratios on a given file.  This is why many large open-source projects offer several downloads compressed by different algorithms — so that users can download the smallest file for which they have a decompression utility.

Comment: I know file size could shrink a lot when there is repeated 0 or 1.But unlike compress, gzip gives an even much bigger file...

Comment: Actually, you didn't compress your tar file.  I have a feeling `gzip` would get you a fairly small output file as well if you had used it.  Your `tar` command actually increased the file size (by placing `tar` headers around the single file).  You actually want `gzip -c mytest.iso > mytest.iso.gz` or `tar -cvzf mytest.iso.tar.gz mytest.iso` (Note the `z`)

Comment: I get a result of 1021K similiar to the compress result of ncompress by adding -z.Thank you!